# How do I convert this to a compareTo line(Java)?

Tags: java, compareto

`while (in > h-1 && n[in-h] >= wrapperTemp)`

I am writing a program but it deals with objects, so using the >,>=, symbols aren't going to help me in this case.

in, h, and wrapperTemp are all variables. 
- this is written in the java language

Comment: It might help if we can see their declarations for more specific advice. As it is, you'll have to write a compare function for the object type that `h` is, then send it `in` and and `n[in-h]`.

Comment: Or you'd use a Comparator.

Comment: What is the type of `in`, `h`, and `wrapperTemp`?

Comment: Please post more code. I do not know what you're asking at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want this

```
while (in.compareTo(h-1) > 0 && n[in-h].compareTo(wrapperTemp) >= 0)
```

Comment: This is form of a Comparable (and very similar to a Comparator).

Comment: @Masud, why do you say that?

Comment: I guess  `in` is primitive type as it was used as array index `n[in-h]`.

Comment: All the wrapper types are `Comparable.` `in` could be a `Integer`.

Comment: well i got it from the shell sort algorithm, its suppose to be used inside an inner class (the iteratorhelper) which im guessing works with objects for the hashtable class i am working on. my professor told me to change the line to comparable/compareTo stuff because of objects

Comment: yes in the shell sort algorithm, they are initialized as ints

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
while (in > h-1 && (n[in-h].compareTo(wrapperTemp) >=0))
```